# Do I need to install SQL SERVER to make a db conncection for asp.net in visual studio , or it is inbuilt in visual studio?

Tags: c#

I want to make a program in c#  in which in which particular persons are selected from the database and then mails are sent to them , so can I accomplish it with with the sql server tools provided in visual studio 2015 or I'll  have to download sql server separately ?

Comment: check if you have installed localdb while installing VS. If localdb is installed no need to download separately.

Comment: Check if you have SQLEXPRESS service in services.msc

Comment: Goto Run(Win+R) and type SSMS and enter .If SQL server is installed then SSMS(Sql Server Management studio ) will open otherwise you need to download and install it or connect to any remote server that has SSMS installed..

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio comes with a localdb and you dont necessarily need SQL Server for with it.
You can add database by Going to Server Explorer > Connect to Database and then Select "Microsoft Sql Server Database file" 
This will add a mdf database file with your Project

If you want to deploy your app with the database you will need to install localdb on client PC too.